# Why is rewrite not working to mask an URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page with an url like this:

```
https://example.net:9000/something
```

I want to be able to access it from here https://example.net/mysite

and mask the url as well so it will always show everything like this before the last /

I tried like this:

RewriteRule ^:9000/something/?$ /mysite/

but it didnt work. Why?

also, I have some other rules on my htaccess that have to stay unaltered:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]           <---everything up to this point has to stay the same

RewriteRule ^:9000/something/?$ /mysite/
</IfModule>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This does not work because your matching pattern in the `RewriteRule` is nonsense. `:9000/something/` is _not_ the path you want to match.

Answer (score 1):

`https:/example.net/` and `https://example.net:9000` hare two separate http hosts that have nothing to do with each other. So you'd actually need the server for `https:/example.net/` to proxy requests meant to be relayed to `https://example.net:9000`.

Assuming that `https:/example.net/` is served by an apache http server (due to how you ask your question), this should be possible using the apache proxy module, either directly:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /mysite/ https://example.com:9000/something/
ProxyPassReverse /mysite/ https://example.com:9000/something/
```

*( Yes, indeed `ProxyRequests off` and not `on`if you implement this in the central server configuration. Leave that line away if you only have access to *dsitributed* configuration files (".htaccess") )*

... or via the rewriting module:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?mysite/(.*)$ https://example.com:9000/something/$1 [P]
```

For that the proxy module and the proxy_http modules have to be loaded in the http server, obviously. The rule has to be implemented in the configuration of the http host serving `https:/example.net/`. If you do not have access to that you can instead implement it in the *distributed* configuration file (typically called ".htaccess") located in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of that host.

Comment: thanks. Can I just add this new line of code to my other rules or I have to rework the older ones in order for all of them to work?

Comment: You remove the useless rule with the "9000" and place one of the two alternatives _above_ all other rules, since it is an exception form the other rules.

Comment: right above Options -MultiViews?

Comment: I'd say below the `RewriteBase ` configuration.

Comment: below the line `RewriteBase /` or below all the rules related to that?

Comment: Below the line. As said: you want to specify that as an exception _before_ any of the other rewrite rules get applied. That is what I assume at least.

Comment: You can also put it above that line, but it has to be below the `RewriteEngine on`.

Comment: Im afraid it didnt work. I tried first with the rule and nothing happens whereas the proxy alternative gives me a 500 error.

Comment: And what does your error log file say what the cause of the status 500 is?

Comment: it says ProxyRequests not allowed here so I guess I cant use that on my server.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. If you use a _distributed_ configuration file and _not_ the preferred central configuration files, then just leave away the `ProxyRequests off`.

Comment: ProxyRequests is set to off . I just copy pasted the lines you posted.

Comment: Sure, and I added that you should leave away that line. That is what caused the status 500. That directive is only allowed in the central configuration, not in distributed configuration file. I understand you use the later, or am I wrong?

Comment: you mean take away that line like in delete it?

Comment: Yep, that is what I meant. _If_ I assume your situation correctly, which you neither confirmed nor denied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245912/discussion-between-arkascha-and-gobler).